# Accessing Microsoft Azure File Storage from ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, connection, storage, azure

I need to store some raster files on Microsoft Azure account.  They are rather large with each file being around 15MB.  It seems the best place on Azure is in File Storage as blobs (unless there is a better place?).

Will I be able to access from inside ArcMap via a Folder connection or a database connection?

Comment: Yes that is possible here is an article on how one person did it https://www.google.com/amp/s/esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/image-services-on-the-web/amp/?client=safari. Your question is not specific enough to recommend alternative solutions or specific details.

Comment: @risail I think your comment would be fine to post as an answer with just a little expansion that summarizes the content of that blog post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you are using the most current version because you did not state the version you are working with.

This [ESRI document](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/registering-your-data-with-arcgis-server-using-manager.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_DCAF9233350D4883B5ED4B2DEE653BCC) outlines how you can connect with either an azure 
storage or an amazon S3 bucket with 10.5 data store.

Esri has documentation on how to complete this in previous versions as well. Strategies for data transfer to Amazon Web Services [10.3.1](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/cloud/amazon/strategies-for-data-transfer-to-aws.htm) or [10.4](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.4/cloud/amazon/strategies-for-data-transfer-to-aws.htm)